# Download file without taking ownership

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a few files in a document library which were never checked-in. I have that list of files available through the document library settings page or in c# using `SPDocumentLibrary.CheckedOutFiles`

Is there a way that I can download those files without taking their ownership via C#.

Answer (score 0):

You don't take ownership if you download files from SharePoint. If you're using the SharePoint CSOM API, you're code look like this:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = creds;

            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
            var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
            var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath,(string)listItem.File.Name);
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {

                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this won't work for files which do not have any published version.